# Azure Batch Re-run job multiple times (On Success, Same Input & Output)

Tags: azure-batch

In Azure Batch, how can we re-run the same job multiple times? I know we can have multiple re-tries if a job fails, but i want to run the same job (with same input) multiple times on success.

If deleting the job and resubmitting is the only option, is there a way to look at job history of the deleted job?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realized that if the job isn't deleted we need to resubmit the job with a different jobId/name. If the job is deleted, then resubmitting the job (through PowerShell etc.) would work fine.